# asp.net core mvc 2.2 validating with a service layer

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I've found this documentation which is actually what I'm looking for, but I'm having some issues with it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs

When decoupling the service layer the code on the website does this:

```
        public ProductController() 
        {
            _service = new ProductService(new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState), new ProductRepository());
        }
```

When I try to translate this to my asp.net core mvc 2.2 project with service I have:

```
// ctor from service
  public ProductService(IProductRepository repo, IValidationDictionary validationDictionary) : IProductService {
 // ...
}

// ctor from controller
public ProductController(IProductService service) {

}


  public class ModelStateWrapper : IValidationDictionary
  {
    private ModelStateDictionary _ModelState;

    public ModelStateWrapper(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
      _ModelState = modelState;
    }

    #region IValidationDictionary members

    public bool IsValid => _ModelState.IsValid;

    public void AddError(string key, string errorMessage)
    {
      _ModelState.AddModelError(key, errorMessage);
    }

    #endregion
  }
```

The problem I have is that I cannot inject the IValidationDictionary validationDictionary parameter.

Now I have to manually pass a parameter **new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState)** each time I call a method from the service that requires validation.
(can't seem set it once because of async service methods)

Is this something that could be solved? As I like the idea of having the validation in the service.

If I could figure out how to pass a parameter of the object to the newly created instance, that would be great:

```
// ctor from controller
public ProductController(IProductService service[use this.ModelState here and pass it to the constructor of the service]) {

}
```

Comment: You are following an ASP.NET Framework guide in an ASP.NET Core project, no wonder nothing works well. It's pretty weird though to be passing ASP.NET Core objects to a layer that's supposed to be decoupled from ASP.NET Core

Comment: services are services in asp.net mvc or asp.net core mvc. repositories are repositories in both. the loose coupling of the ModelState itself goes via the IValidationDictionary. 
The code can work perfectly in asp.net core mvc or asp.net mvc. Only thing is that I'm looking to have it working with the build in dependency injection of asp.net core.  so that I can pass a parameter of controller when creating a service instance. (looking for a kind of factory if that exists).

Comment: The two do not handle validation the same way. As such, something you build based on ASP.NET MVC doesn't work for ASP.NET Core.

Comment: i'm just trying to get validation working in services. and figuring a way so that I can still work with ModelState from inside my services, loosely coupled. I'm using the idea of the link, which is indeed for ASP.NET MVC and not for core. (I know that!). But I'm actually stuck with the ModelState, how this could be used or if there is any other way to do the validation centrally in services?

Comment: I'm testing Core out and struggling with the same thing. Did you resolve this or find a useful tutorial / example project / video / book that helped? Both Camilo & Chis have pointed out Framework concepts won't work on Core projects, but a link to a resource would be really helpful.

Comment: I think we are in the same page :)  it's been awhile now, did you get any solution? @jimmy juFo

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it with .NET Core 5.0

In Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
    ...
}
```

In Controller

```
AccountService _service;

public AccountController(IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor)
{
      //this.actionContextAccessor = actionContextAccessor;
      _service = new AccountService(actionContextAccessor);
 }
```

In Service Layer class

```
public class AccountService
    {    
        private readonly IActionContextAccessor _actionContextAccessor;
        public AccountService(IActionContextAccessor actionContextAccessor)
        {
            _actionContextAccessor = actionContextAccessor;
        }

        public void Login(string emailAddress, string password)
        {  
            _actionContextAccessor.ActionContext.ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Your error message");
        }
    }
```

In Action, you use like

```
   _service.Login(model.Email, model.Password);

  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
      return View(model);
```